# How to improve the rendering of a custom 'data calendar' in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been asked to improve a ASP.Net C# page. It currently shows a years worth of daily prices for a product. The page looks similar to a wall planner, with each input control showing a price for that day.

The page will be used to change the price of this product for that year. Currently the 'wall planner' table control is being generated cell-by-cell in the code behind.

There is a lot of code used to implement this but essentially it does the following.

**A table is built... dynamically**

1. New Table control defined
2. 12 new TableRow controls defined (months)
3. Each row has 31 TableCell controls added to it (Each with a unique id e.g. cell_yy_mm_dd)

**Its filled with data**

1. 365 days of prices are retrieved from the database (Price and Date).
2. Foreach used to loop over the dataset
3. Date checked with the TableCells id. If there is a match, a new TextBox is added to the cell.

This is causing a huge strain on the server (specifically memory usage). It seems so over engineered there must be a better way of doing it!

What would be a better method to implement such functionality?

Comment: Have you profiled and checked performance? Have the results pinpointed this page as the culprit? What in the process you described is causing the strain?

Comment: Yes, profiled with ANTS and this page is the main culprit.

Comment: What _in_ the page is the problem? Which specific process?

Comment: Don't forget, this is, at minimum 1 Table + 12 TableRow + 31 * 12 TableCell + 31 * 12 TextBox = 757 unique controls that need to be managed by the server.  If nothing else, that's one helluva post-back.

Comment: @Oded the biggest problem seems to be findControl method which is being called for every cell in the table!

Comment: @jklemmack yes it's huge, they've got a load of memory allocated to the server but it's just paging to disk now! A re-write is definately in order!

Comment: I see. If the new controls are added dynamically, you could store references to them in variables (could use arrays/lists) and instead of `findControl` simply call and update the variables directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would solve it. Using two repeaters, one for the months and one for the days.
Using the current calendar I can than from code generate the months and the days using linq and left join with the values from the db on the Date.
Code

```
//The values from the DB
var values = new List<DateValue>()
{ 
    new DateValue(){ Date = new DateTime(2012, 1, 12), Value = 5000 },  
    new DateValue(){ Date = new DateTime(2012, 11, 15), Value = 3000 }
};

var year = DateTime.Now.Year;
var cal = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Calendar;

//Generate the months and dates and left join with the values from the DB
var q = from month in Enumerable.Range(1, cal.GetMonthsInYear(year))
        select new
        {
            Dates = from date in Enumerable.Range(1, 
                        cal.GetDaysInMonth(year, month))
                        .Select(day => new DateTime(year, month, day))
                    join tmp in values on date equals tmp.Date into g
                    from value in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new
                    {
                        Date = date,
                        Value = value == null ? new Nullable<Decimal>() : value.Value
                    }
        };

//bind the query to the outer repeater
repMonths.DataSource = q;
repMonths.DataBind();
```

DTO filled from DB

```
public class DateValue
{
     public DateTime Date { get; set; }
     public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

ASPX

```
<table border="1">
      <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repMonths">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repDays" DataSource='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Dates") %>'>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <td>
                                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Value")  %>
                            </td>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

the two things I would check are

1. the size of viewstate. this can grow out of hand quickly with a large number of server controls
2. how the data is queried. poor queries and non-indexed schemas can lead to slow performance

can we assume the table is built using the webforms table object? if so this is your problem. this is creating a huge, unnecessary tax on viewstate. instead build up objects to represent the UI data structure. from this collection of objects create the use using standard html objects (not webforms server controls).

for example you might use a repeater and disable viewstate for that specific control. using the header, footer and body templates, build out an html table

```
<asp:repeater id="..." EnableViewState="false">
    <headertempalte>
         <table>
             <thead>
                 <tr>
                   <th>...</th>
                   <th>...</th>
                 </tr>
             </thead>
             <body>
    </headertemplate>
    <footertemplate>
             </body>
             <tfoot>
                 ...
             </tfoot>
        </table>
    </footertemplate>
    <itemtemplate>
         <tr>
            <td><%=Eval("...")%></td>
            <td><%=Eval("...")%></td>
         </tr>
    </itemtemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```

that just one example and I'm sure the templates would need adjustments to fix your exact layout, but that should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks Jason, your comment on using the WebForms Table object and ViewState will help!